# subquery not working and giving two columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:
I want the subquery to return only ids , but it is also returning distance. Also, i can't remove the distance column as it is used in having.

```
select * from offers  offer_id in (SELECT (((acos(sin((30.1*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))
+cos((30.1*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180))
* cos(((70.2- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
as distance,id
FROM id_master HAVING distance <=4)
```

I have tried many ways but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the distance expression into a `WHERE` clause and remove it from the select list.

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE offer_id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM id_master
    WHERE
        (((acos(sin((30.1*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))
        + cos((30.1*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) *
        cos(((70.2- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) <= 4
)
```

Comment: Reload your page...I had a rogue `distance` alias in my query from where I copied from your question.